# R-shiny: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

So I am using mpg dataset to practice my R-shiny skills, but I encountered a problem.

I want to write a app which I could choose different variables to make graph, if it involves at least one discrete variable, then I draw a geom_boxplot, else, I will just draw a geom_point.

My ui.R looks like this:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "var1",
                  label = "Choose x variable",
                  choices = 
                    names(mpg)
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = "var2",
                  label = "Choose y variable",
                  choices = 
                    names(mpg))
      ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

And
My server.R looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

     if(typeof(mpg[, input$var1]) == "chr" ||
        typeof(mpg[, input$var2]) == "chr")
     {
       ggplot(data = mpg) +
         geom_boxplot(mapping =
                          aes(x = mpg[, input$var1],
                              y = mpg[, input$var2])) +
         xlab(input$var1) +
         ylab(input$var2) +
         ggtitle(paste("Plot", input$var1, "vs", input$var2))
     }

     else
     {
      ggplot(data = mpg) +
        geom_point(mapping =
                     aes(x = mpg[, input$var1],
                         y = mpg[, input$var2])) +
        xlab(input$var1) +
        ylab(input$var2) +
        ggtitle(paste("Plot", input$var1, "vs", input$var2))
     }
  })
})
```

But it simply does not work! When I choose discrete variable, it will return me an error message says "Discrete value applied to continuous scale". However, if I both choose continuous value, it seems to be work fine.

Why it shows such an error message like that? 
Please help me!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here all on the server side:

**One:** If you check an example of your `typeof` you'll see that you always get a list:

```
typeof(mpg[,"model"])
#[1] "list"
typeof(mpg[,"displ"])
#[1] "list"
```

This is because `[` doesn't extract the actual element, but the list containing that element. From `?"["`:

> Indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the specified element(s).

Rather you should use `typeof(mpg[[input$var1]])`, etc because you want to extract the element of the list (not the list that contains the element).

**Two:**

There is actually a specific function in `ggplot`, `aes_string` which selects the columns to plot based on a string.

Incorporating these two changes should make your shiny app work. I also simplified you server a bit to get rid of the common `ggplot` code.

```
server <- function(input,output){

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    p <- ggplot(mpg) + xlab(input$var1) +
                       ylab(input$var2) +
                       ggtitle(paste("Plot", input$var1, "vs", input$var2))

    if(typeof(mpg[[input$var1]]) == "character" |
       typeof(mpg[[input$var2]]) == "character")
    {
      p <- p + geom_boxplot(mapping =
                       aes_string(x = input$var1,
                                  y = input$var2))
    }

    else
    {
     p <- p + geom_point(mapping =
                     aes_string(x = input$var1,
                                y = input$var2))
    }

    return(p)

  })
}
```